# How to get the Serial Number of the Remote Device over Bluetooth?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

In my application, I discovered bluetooth devices and thus got the following ---

- *Name of Bluetooth Device.*
- *Hardware address of Bluetooth Device.*

This is done by getting `BluetoothDevice` object for each discovered device and calling 
`object.getName()` and `object.getAddress()`.

I also want to get the **Serial number** of each discovered bluetooth device.

I know to get the serial number of my own device as ---

```
android.os.Build.SERIAL
```

Comment: There is no bluetooth specification to get that information. However, the bluetooth MAC address is guaranteed unique. Use that.

Comment: Yes I am currently using MAC address as this is the only option I found when I read docs. There is no such information related to Remote Bluetooth Serial. Thanks.

Comment: There is no such information, because there is no such concept.

Comment: You need to know which service / characteristics holds the serial number information of the device and you have to read that specifically (this needs connecting to the device). This could be defferent for different type of Bluetooth devices / different BLE profiles. Usually there is a `device information` service though and under this service there is a `Serial number string` characteristic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

(Updated URLs)

Many bluetooth low energy profiles provide a *service* called `Device Information`.
Assigned UUID: `0x180A`
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services/

Under this *service* there is a `Serial Number String` *characteristic* which can hold a serial number specific to the Bluetooth low energy device.
Assigned UUID: `0x2A25`
https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/characteristics/

This is optional though and not all BLE profiles will have it, and you have to connect to the device to retrieve this information.

Comment: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/characteristics/